# Database schema for purpose of drop down list with custom add option

Tags: database

I'm working on some database schema which includes maintenance task, that you can register for your vehicle. Right now, I'm facing some issue, caused by some sort of use case where drop-down list should be populated with default maintenance task (added by system administrator) with "add custom maintenance task" feature. In order to better depict, user can add own imaginary maintenance task if she didn't find any on drop-down list. What is more, user can only view task created by administrator and herselft. So other user can add the same maintenance task as well in order to find it on her drop-down list later on.

The point is, I don't know which database schema fits better to this case.
Below is one to go for (it's only based on sight):
[image]

I'd like to know is it a good database design for this sort of use case or there are much better in a field of database design? Of course, i don't want my database to bloat too much :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It strange to answer own question, but i came up with solution (maybe not perfect, but I will find out during further tests). I made it by unique composite key. I don't need third table anymore. Presently there are left over only two tables from above model such as: Maintenance_Task and Maintenance_Task_Category.
I also added extra column to Maintenance_Task table, which is called: created_by, and this is a foreign key to user core table. So to speak, unique composite key contains either name of maintenance task and created_by (fk).
To sum up, user can add custom maintenance task only once for her.
There is also a rule: If admin add maintenance task before user, user won't be able to add it (she will ony see wanted maintenance task on drop-down list, but without ability to add one another). This rule will be implemented in application domain (backend).

Thanks for your help, anyway.
Maybe someone will take adventage of some content from this topic.